# Как правильно сохранять большие списки данных в реальном времени, не нагружая компьютер.

Tags: c#

Нужно сохранять списки строк в реальном времени. Но Списки постоянно пополняются и необходимо полученные списки сохранять на диске. Как это сделать не напрягая сильно жесткий диск. Язык C#

Comment: Можно использовать БД для этих целей?

Comment: Ээээ... Буферизация, конечно. Которая, кстати, встроена в стандартную библиотеку. Просто не закрывайте/открывайте файл каждый раз пи записи новой строки.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно открыть файл и записывать туда. В промежутках между записью файл не закрывать, чтобы не тратить время на его открытие. После завершения обработки всех строк файл можно закрыть.